# Implement two notification systems for an event with Strategy pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have a list of subscribes in my database

```
Subscriber:
string Name      <- required
string Phone     <- required
string EventName <- required
string Email     <- optional
```

The subscriber can subscribe on some event by its name (`EventName`).

When an event occurs, I need to send a notification to all subscribers (where `EventName==the event which occurred`) via Email or SMS. If `Email` is not null, then send email. If `Email` is null, send SMS to `Phone`.

I my business logic I created this abstraction:

```
public interface INotification
{
   Task Send(string message, IEnumerable<Subscriber> subscribers);
}
```

and use it in event handler

```
var subscribes = _db.Subscribers.Where(x => x.EventName == event);
await _notification.Send(message, subscribes);
```

Then I'm going to use a Strategy pattern.

```
public interface INotificationStartegy
{
   Task Send(string message, string to);
}
public interface EmailNotificationStartegy : INotificationStartegy
{
   /// 
}
public interface SmsNotificationStartegy : INotificationStartegy
{
   /// 
}
```

Here is an example of `INotification` implementation

```
public class Notification : INotification
{
  public Notification(SmsNotificationStartegy smsSender, EmailNotificationStartegy emailSender) =>
     (_smsSender, _emailSender);

  public async Task Send(string message, IEnumerable<Subscriber> subscribers)
  {   
    foreach(Subscriber sub in subscribers)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sub.Email)
        {
            await _emailSender.Send(message, sub.Email);
        } else {
            await _smsSender.Send(message, sub.Phone);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Could you please suggest if it is a proper way to use Strategy? I thought the Strategy pattern can help us to avoid if/switch in a code, but who will decide what strategy to use then? I'm confused, do I really need this `INotification` abstraction or can I use that `forearch` directly in my event handler?

Could anyone explain benefits of `INotification`? Or is it a wrong implementation?

What if I need to add one more strategy, I should always modify Notification? Are there any ways how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the strategy pattern. In your implementation you are creating single concrete `notification` object that is supposed to handle multiple functions for which you tried to implement this pattern.
So in my mind, you would have a single Notification strategy, to which you would inject by constructor a single concrete implementation of INotification object, be it `EmailNotification` or `SmsNotification`.

To have multiple possible receivers that can decide if they can send a notification would be a job for mediator pattern.

If you really do not want to use mediator, then simplest solution would be to create multiple `NotificationStrategy` objects, each with single `INotification` injected and use / iterate through them - 2 different notification types = 2 strategy objects each with different `INotification` implementation injected.

Thanks to this, no more if-elsing - each `INotification` implementation decides for itself if notifying is possible for it's particular way with given data.

Another alternative (with some if-else but compatible more or less with Strategy pattern) would be to firstly analyse given data and then, when you know what you have, creating a proper strategy objects with injected adequate `INotification` concrete objects.

Edit for minimal working example for strategy pattern with multiple dispatchers:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var subscribers = new List<Subscriber>(); // Data of subscribers - empty just for simplicity
        
        // Decide which strategy is good - sms, email or both?
        // use if-else, switch, pattern matching, external service or something else
        // Combine subscribers for each strategy into lists / other collections
        var smsSubscribers = new List<Subscriber>();
        var emailSubscribers = new List<Subscriber>();
        
        var smsDispatcher = new Dispatcher(new SmsStrategy());
        var emailDispatcher = new Dispatcher(new EmailStrategy());
        
        foreach(var entry in smsSubscribers)
        {
            await smsDispatcher.Send("message...", smsSubscribers);
        }
        
        foreach(var entry in emailSubscribers)
        {
            await emailDispatcher.Send("message...", smsSubscribers);
        }   
    }
    
    public class Dispatcher
    {
        INotificationStrategy _strategy;
        
        public Dispatcher(INotificationStrategy strategy)
        {
            _strategy = strategy;
        }
        
        public Task Send(string message, IEnumerable<Subscriber> subscribers)
        {
            return _strategy.Send(message, subscribers);
        }
    }
    
    public interface INotificationStrategy
    {
       Task Send(string message, IEnumerable<Subscriber> subscribers);
    }
    
    public class EmailStrategy : INotificationStrategy
    {
        public Task Send(string message, IEnumerable<Subscriber> subscribers)
        {
            // Check data, iterate over subscribers, decide if sending EMAIL is possible etc and SEND.
            return Task.CompletedTask; // Only here to remove compiler error
        }
    }
    
    public class SmsStrategy : INotificationStrategy
    {
        public Task Send(string message, IEnumerable<Subscriber> subscribers)
        {
            // Check data, iterate over subscribers, decide if sending SMS is possible etc and SEND.
            return Task.CompletedTask; // Only here to remove compiler error
        }
    }
    
    public class Subscriber
    {
        // Some subscriber data...
    }
}
```

Mind, that for multiple recipients a [mediator](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/mediator) patter would be more useful - check the **mediatr** project.

Comment: thank you for this. could you please add some code samples to a better understanding of your concepts? I'm new and I think I didn't catch all things

Comment: OK, edited my answer with some super - basic example.